# PHP variables not working on new server

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for any help. So I am on a shared host and switching hosts and the code I had worked on old host but it is not working on new one. I am using this to call out for images.

I have a file in /includes/ called status.php and has listed the variables that I want to call out. On the index.php page it has code like below and I can change the image name and web link.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="3u 12u(mobile)">
        <section>
            <a href="<?=$nwwnjcem?>"><img src="images/celebs/nwwnjce_<?=$nwwnjce?>.jpg" alt="Nerds with Words" /></a>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Is there anything maybe not setup correctly on the new server for php that you can think of that would cause this?

Thanks Again

Some more info Running PHP 5.5.9

Host is telling me

When ever we load that page, the /var/log/apache2/error.log 
fills up with messages:
[Wed Mar 22 00:17:13.751391 2017] [:error] [pid 19619] [client 68.4.204.93:49640] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: heidit in /var/www/index.php on line 272, referer: http://#########.org/

Comment: `<?php echo $nwwnjcem; ?>`

Comment: @DrKey Those PHP short tags are valid syntax.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Also, do you get any errors?

Comment: @JohnConde They are valid, but they are not always enabled: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694

Comment: @JeremiahMegel That's why I asked about their version. Unless it's really old (and no longer supported) this should work.

Comment: @DrKey there is no output of that variable, that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to everyone, it was you asking questions that gave me ideas and yes the short tags were off on new server. Once they were turned on they work!

Thanks again.